# Android: correctly stopping an async task

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service, android-sqlite, android-sensors

I have an app designed to record sensor data every 10ms and store into a SQLite db on the phone. I'm doing the db inserts as an async task because they happen so fast and there are so many of them that they slow down navigation noticeably. However, I'm occasionally running into problems when trying to stop the recording.

In one of my fragments there is a start stop button. Press it to record. Press it again to stop recording. The `onClick` looks like this:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!recordingStarted){

            recordingStarted = true;
            mainActivity.startService(new Intent(mainActivity, SensorService.class));
            startButton.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.start_button_label_stop));
            Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Recording...", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            mainActivity.stopService(new Intent(mainActivity, SensorService.class));
            startButton.setEnabled(false);
            Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Recording stopped.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

When recording is started, the `SensorService` class is called up. That just registers listeners, starts a service so I can collect data when the screen is off, calculates some sensor things etc. This is where my async task lies. The only interesting parts of that class are:

```
public class SensorService extends Service implements SensorEventListener {

    public BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onReceive("+intent+")");

            if (!intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
                return;
            }

            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Runnable executing...");
                    unregisterListener();
                    registerListener();
                }
            };

            new Handler().postDelayed(runnable, SCREEN_OFF_RECEIVER_DELAY);
        }
    };

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        sensor = event.sensor;

        int i = sensor.getType();
        if (i == MainActivity.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            accelerometerMatrix = event.values;
        } else if (i == MainActivity.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {
            gyroscopeMatrix = event.values;
        } else if (i == MainActivity.TYPE_GRAVITY) {
            gravityMatrix = event.values;
        } else if (i == MainActivity.TYPE_MAGNETIC) {
            magneticMatrix = event.values;
        }

        long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long diffTime = (curTime - lastUpdate);

        // only allow one update every POLL_FREQUENCY.
        if(diffTime > POLL_FREQUENCY) {
            lastUpdate = curTime;

            //cut a bunch of stuff here to save space

            //insert into database
            new InsertSensorDataTask().execute();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        dbHelper = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());

        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(MainActivity.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        gyroscope = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(MainActivity.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);
        gravity = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(MainActivity.TYPE_GRAVITY);
        magnetic = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(MainActivity.TYPE_MAGNETIC);

        PowerManager manager =
                (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = manager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);

        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        unregisterListener();
        wakeLock.release();
        dbHelper.close();
        stopForeground(true);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        startForeground(Process.myPid(), new Notification());
        registerListener();
        wakeLock.acquire();

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private class InsertSensorDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean> {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                dbHelper.insertData(Short.parseShort(MainActivity.subInfo.get("subNum")), System.currentTimeMillis(),
                        accelerometerMatrix[0], accelerometerMatrix[1], accelerometerMatrix[2],
                        accelerometerWorldMatrix[0], accelerometerWorldMatrix[1], accelerometerWorldMatrix[2],
                        gyroscopeMatrix[0], gyroscopeMatrix[1], gyroscopeMatrix[2]);
                return true;
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "insertData: " + e.getMessage(), e);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I hit the stop button, that will immediately call `stopService` in the `onClick`, which I believe will call `onDestroy` in the `SensorService`. However I run into conditions where stop is pressed, listeners are unregistered, databases are closed, but there are still async tasks running in the background. My guess is that they're still completing their final tasks before actually stopping. This runs me into exception territory because then the async code is trying to insert data into a database that is now closed. I could just catch those and ignore them, but I want to figure out the correct way to handle this type of situation

How should I refactor my code to allow for the async tasks to finish? Because this isn't 1 big job but rather thousands of small db insert jobs, I would have imagined they could stop rather quickly so I'm surprised that I keep running into these closed db exception problems

Is there a way to tell when all async tasks are done? Maybe I could use that as a condition in `onDestroy` before anything gets closed?

Or would it be worth moving away from async tasks altogether? I mostly just want to avoid running these db inserts in the main UI thread

Comment: put a toast in OnDestroy of AsynTask! you will know if it's stoping or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it could be worse than that. When you call execute(), you actually add a task to a queue.  A single thread goes through the queue and runs the tasks one at a time.  So you could have multiple tasks queued that won't be canceled.  By the way this is 1 shared thread for all async tasks, so if you have other tasks they can also hold up things.

There's two solutions here.  The first is to have an isCanceled variable at the service level that all async tasks look at at the start of doInBackground and immediately exit if that is set.

The second is I think a better solution.  Create a Thread.  The Thread should look like this:

```
while(!isCanceled) {
  insertData = BlockingQueue.take()
  //insert insertData
}
```

Your sensor data callback can then add an item to this queue, and your onStop can just cancel the thread and empty the queue.

Comment: So I just did some googling as I've never played with threads before. However I couldn't find any classes/methods called `synchronizedQueue` or `blockingGet`. Could you expand a bit on what the code would actually look like and/or point me in the direction of where I'd find those methods?

Comment: A BlockingQueue would be the right interface-  any subset of that.  Basically it has a function take() that will either return the head of the queue or if the queue is empty will wait until data has been added by another thread, then return that.  I've updated my answer with the right names